# slideToggle - dropdown menu closes and opens when a user clicks on nav menu twice

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I’ve been building this navigation and it works how I want to except for 1 issue.

**The issue:** When a user clicks on the same navigation menu twice the dropdown menu closes and opens. I just need the menu to close alongside removing the `active` class when a user clicks on the same nav menu the second time.

How do I resolve this issue?

Below is my code.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.navigationV1 ul.top-level-menu .label').on('click', function() {
    // Close already opened menus
    $('.label.active').removeClass('active').siblings('.drop-down-menu').slideUp();
    // Toggle top nav links
    $(this).siblings('.drop-down-menu').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });

});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #666;
}

.drop-down-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigationV1 top-level-menu label">

  <div class="descendant-links-container">
    <ul class="top-level-menu">

      <li>
        <a class="label">Menu 1</a>

        <ul class="drop-down-menu">
          <li>
            <a>Drop-down-menu 1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a class="label">Menu 2</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a class="label">Menu 3</a>
        <ul class="drop-down-menu">
          <li>
            <a>Drop-down-menu 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Add an if statement and check if this [has](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) the active class.  If it does, just close it, else run the code that you have.

Comment: I'm trying that now my friend but can't get the end result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the hasClass method in jQuery will let you check if the 'active' class is already present on the label. In the function below `$(this).hasClass("active")` returns true or false.  You can then use this value to simply close the current menu when true or if it's false, just run your normal code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".navigationV1 ul.top-level-menu .label").on("click", handleNavClick);

  function handleNavClick() {
    const isActive = $(this).hasClass("active");
    if (isActive) {
      $(this).siblings(".drop-down-menu").slideToggle();
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
    } else {
      // Close already opened menus
      $(".active").removeClass("active").siblings(".drop-down-menu").slideUp();
      // Toggle top nav links
      $(this).siblings(".drop-down-menu").slideToggle();
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That solution worked like a charm my friend. You are a JS ninja. Thank you!